# Set umask for systemd service, but files created by the process are still using the default

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, systemd

This is the unit for the Transmission torrent client, which was compiled and installed from source.

*/etc/systemd/system/transmission.service*:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Start the Transmission daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=_transmission
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/transmission-daemon --foreground
UMask=0002

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I need it to use umask 0002, but it still creates new files with the default 0022.

> `_transmission` is a system user, but it has a home folder. All other options are default. It has no default group (gid "nogroup").

### Things I've tried

- `systemctl daemon-reload`
- `systemctl restart transmission.service`
- Reboot

### System info

- Hardware: Raspberry Pi 4B (arm64)
- OS: Raspberry Pi OS (based on Debian bookworm)
- systemd 252

Comment: Does this answer at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/157471) help?

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I didn't think of looking in Transmission settings. Still, I wanted to understand why systemd can't change that. I suppose Transmission is overriding it internally.
[Found the documentation](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/blob/3cd66899fe5c8434aef71e179024cf6eaa0d5691/docs/Editing-Configuration-Files.md#files-and-locations) for the umask option in Transmission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems Transmission overrides the umask internally, so systemd cannot change it. Transmission lets you change the umask with a configuration option, which is documented [here](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/blob/3cd66899fe5c8434aef71e179024cf6eaa0d5691/docs/Editing-Configuration-Files.md#files-and-locations).

> umask: String (default = "022") Sets Transmission's file mode creation mask. See the umask(2) manpage for more information.

---

I was also trying to do the same for the Syncthing process, and the systemd method works. It's even [documented here](https://docs.syncthing.net/users/autostart.html#permissions). However, it only honors the umask if you set "ignore permissions" on the folders.

> If you enabled the Ignore Permissions option in the Syncthing client’s folder settings, then you will also need to add the line UMask=0002 (or any other umask setting you like) in the [Service] section of the syncthing@.service file.